# How to assign an Associative array to a list component in FLEX 4.6

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, arraylist, associative-array

I would like to print the values of my associative array in a list. Im doing this, but i think the IList class uses the common index [0]..[n] to print the elements (im not sure of this)

my code(example):

```
private var arr = new Array();
private var arrList: new ArrayList(arr);


private function init()
{
  arr["hello"]="world";
  list.dataProvider = arrList; //the component was instanced before
}
```

I have been debbugging and the arrList updates the info with elements of arr, but list component dont show anything.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: What you're talking about is an Object or a Dictionary. If you're getting this to work with an Array it's because you're using its "ObjectNess" not its "Arrayness." Probably your best bet would be to go with XML and an XMLListColection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataProvider` appears to accept `key:value` pairs as `label` and `data` object entries pushed to an array which is mirrored the actual `List`.  Personally, I prefer to roll with my own list class, so I'm not speaking from `List` object experience.  See [Adobe's documentation for List.dataProvider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002562.html) for more info.

```
private var foo:Object = {
    "hello":"world",
    "apple":"pie",
    "orange":"juice"
}

var dpArr:Array = [];
list.dataProvider = dpArr;

for (var key:String in foo) {
    dpArr.addItem({label:key, data:foo[key]});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what i need. I was trying with spark controls in flex, but those controls dont use the `dataProvider`, instead with mx controls i could do this!